# Symfony 3 update dependencies conflicts

Tags: symfony, dependencies, composer-php, symfony-2.7, symfony3.x

Trying to update the project from Symfony 2.7 to 3.x, when i run a composer **update** i get dependency conflicts between the different bundles i'm using, for example:

```
friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle 1.5.3 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.0
lunetics/locale-bundle 2.4.5 requires symfony/framework-bundle ^2.8|^3.0
```

and

```
symfony/framework-bundle 3.3.x-dev conflicts with symfony/symfony[v3.0.0]
```

is there a workaround to solve the conflicts without disabling the bundles ?

my composer.json file:
https://pastebin.com/tAsij64M

Comment: I'd highly suggest first going to Symfony 2.8 and working out all of the reported deprecations first, From there, you can much more safely go on to 3.3.  There are also some blog posts (eg KNPUniversity) and some tools to help a lot.

Comment: The tool is [Symfony deprecation detector](https://github.com/sensiolabs-de/deprecation-detector)

Comment: I have already used Symfony deprecation Detector along with Symfony Upgrade Fixer to manage depredations, i have read on KNPUniversity that you can update directly to 3.x from 2.7 without migrating to 2.8 first, thanks for your feedback Alister.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update :

- jsrouting-bundle to ^1.6 in order to be compatible with framework-bundle 3.*
- symfony to 3.3 or downgrade framework-bundle to 3.0.* because symfony and framework-bundle must have the same version

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Fabien, 
Upgrading all of jsrouting-bundle to ^1.6, framework-bundle to ^3.0 and Symfony to 3.1 solved the conflicts with framework-bundle.